# Production Database handling in Maven

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, deployment

I have written a REST webservice using JAX-RS and I currently prepare my test database using DbUnit. However, if I would now deploy may application, this would not fit my needs anymore. Thus, I am looking for a maven plugin that lets me handle the preparation and update of the production database. So I need something that creates my tables and inserts default data when I deploy my service for the first time and updates the tables when I deploy new releases, when the service is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of useful frameworks for this usecase.

Have a look at:

- [FlyWay](http://flywaydb.org/)
- and [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)

Both can handle your use case quite neatly. The main difference is the way how migrations are defined, flyway uses SQL and Javacode based migrations, Liquibase uses XML.

My personal preference lies with FlyWay, as I find it more natural.

Comment: Actually you can define all your DDL in SQL in liquibase now.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan That was new to me, thanks for the info.

Comment: A related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418814/db-migration-tool-liquibase-or-flyway/